# Year doesn't appear sometimes in "Top Posts" from new user profile

Tags: bug, profile-page

Everything's said in the title.

Here's an example from my profile : some posts from 2014 appears such as, some don't.
[image]

Comment: [status-bydesign] - If the post is recent enough, the year is omitted.

Answer (score 1):

Works as designed, the year is included if it's necessary. The difference in your example between June 2014 and April 2014 is that it's April 2015 now, so there's a need to differentiate April last year against April this year. That doesn't exist for June because you can't possibly have taken actions in June 2015 yet.

Comment: Indeed, sorry for the dup'!